# What is the point of returning a const alias from a function

Tags: c++, function, return, constants

Please look at the following code and help me understand:
Why the functionality to return a const alias to a literal like my f2 function exists. I don't understand what the point is.
The difference between f2 and f3 is that const does allow me to put a literal in the return statement, but again why?

Any help in understanding this is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

const int f1(int a)
{
    return 15;
}

const int& f2(int a)
{
    return 14;
}

int& f3(int a)
{
    a = 12;
    return a;
}

int main()
{

    auto a{ 10 };
    auto b = f1(a);
    auto c = f2(a);
    auto d = f3(a);

    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << std::endl;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;
    d = 4;
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Using the reference returned from `f2` and `f3` causes undefined behavior. There is not much more to say. Returning `const int` from `f1` does not make sense. Anyway, generally, the difference is that _const-lvalue-references_ may be bound to temporaries (rvalues), while _non-const-lvalue-references_ may not.

Comment: An alias is a secondary name for a type. What you are talking about are references.

Comment: A good compiler warns you about this code. This code is wrong and can crash (see "Segmentation fault" at the end): https://wandbox.org/permlink/OAO8QVbZ3FgAJ4GX

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification. I know there is major problems with the code, but I was unclear why it was allowed, and what actually happened. Again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both `f2` and `f3` have undefined behaviour. You are returning references to local variables. Those local variables are destroyed when the function ends, and the reference is dangling.

The difference between a const reference, and a non-const reference is that a const reference can bind to both rvalues and lvalues.

For non-const references you have to distinguish between lvalue-reference(`int&`) and rvalue-reference(`int&&`).

So using the function signature `int&& f2(int a)` would also compile, but equally have undefined behaviour.

The main reason this is usefull is because when we pass a reference to a function, the function signature tell us if we are expecting an lvalue or an rvalue. We can also overload both and decide to move/copy depending on what we get.

In the case where we don't care, or if we only want to read from the value we can use a const reference and be able to accept both lvalues and rvalues that are passed in.

```
void foo(MyClass& mc) {
    // We know mc is an lvalue.
    // We could copy mc, or modify it if we want to use it as an output parameter.
}

void foo(MyClass&& mc) {
    // We know mc is an rvalue.
    // We know it would be safe to move from mc in this case.
}

MyClass mc;
foo(mc); // Callsthe first overload
foo(MyClass{}); // Calls the second overload

// The two functions above can be overloaded, so we can make sure we deal
// with both cases in the right way

void foo2(const MyClass& mc) {
    // This can be both an rvalue or lvalue.
    // We don't really care since the reference
    // is const we are only going to read from it.
}

foo2(mc); // Both calls work
foo2(MyClass{});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `b`, `c` and `d` variables in main are initialized with a copy of what the functions return. No matter if they return a copy, a ref or a const ref.

To keep the *attributes* of the returned value, let's change the first lines in main:

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto a{ 10 };
    auto& b = f1(a); // Does not compile, a ref can't be tied to a r-value
    auto& c = f2(a); // Ok, c's type is 'const int&'
    auto& d = f3(a); // Ok, d's type is 'int&'

    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << std::endl;
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3; // Does not compile. c is a ref to a const
    d = 4;
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << std::endl;
}
```

So, the point is you can return a reference to an internal variable, but now allowing the caller to change it. Doing so (instead of returning a copy), you

- avoid the copy
- allow the caller to see any later change

Not much sense for the code above, but think of a method inside a class, where the internal variable can be changed in other ways.

Besides the return type, f2 and f3 are not correct, as they return a reference to a not-in-memory (f2) or temporary object (f3).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you write a function that needs to return a complex object, but this object shouldn't be modified (such as pointer to a shared resource, class-property, some sort a singleton data and so on).
For the sake of this answer, lets assume the type in "struct Point".
You have 2 options to do so:

1. return it by value, which will create a deep copy of its primitive type members and a shallow copy of its by-reference-types members:
   const struct Point f2(...)
2. return it by reference, which will copy only the pointer to the object:
   const struct Point* f2()
   const struct Point& f2()

both are valid, while the second one has the advantage when dealing with heavy objects.

In the code you provided you do not see the difference because "int" is a primitive type which means it has known way to be copied. This means var "c" isn't actually an alias nor a const, its an int who took its value from the return type of f2